# Как отключить контекстное меню для браузера internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html

Как на сайте отключить появление контекстного меню для ссылок PS  браузера internet explorer, В Chrome я уже отключил с помощью oncontextmenu="return false" но данная глушилка не работает для ie. Есть альтернативный вариант? Тоесть при наводе на ссылку и нажимая правую кнопку мыши меню не появлялась, или для мобильного ие при долгом удержание ссылки не выходило меню Открыть в новом окне копировать ссылку и т.д Можно ли это сделать для гребенного IE?

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот вариант у меня работает везде

```js
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open('https://ya.ru', '_blank');
})

document.querySelector('img').oncontextmenu = function() {
  return false;
};
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/07/cb/fc/07cbfcc0-ac70-8fb3-0ae8-6ba4648d58f2/pr_source.png/100x100bb-85.jpg">
```

Comment: Да он работает но только для <img src='/ а если это не просто картинка, а ссылочная картинка то контекстное меню так и появляется

Comment: Пробовал так <а hrеf='/мой сайт.ком/sur/'><img src='/dis/cssimg/co.png' oncontextmenu='return false'></а> но все так же контекстное меню всплывает :(

Comment: Проверяй везде, где хочешь....  Работает))))

Comment: Ты кстати на каком `IE` проверяешь?)))

Comment: Air, IE 7, и на мобильном версию не знаю

Comment: Прости друг, но я даже думать не хочу о нем...))))  Зачем это тебе надо....???

Comment: air, ну что бы усложнить воровство иконок и картинок с моего сайта) Да кстате в CSS img добавил webkit, user-select:none и т.д вот на некоторых картинках и ссылках контекстное меню не всплывает а на некоторых всплывает это как? :) А вот про код вставил в чистый файл .js

Comment: Подумай, своровать можно в любом случае...... А теперь, вопрос...  человек который может обойти твою защиту, будет заморачиваться  и через `IE-7`  воровать картинки?  Не тот вариант защиты ты ищешь... А что если просто отключить у браузера `JS`, что тогда? Лучше сделай фон картинки меткой, которые показываются...